# Apache opens index.html/ instead of index.html

Tags: apache

I'm on ubuntu 14.04 and apache 2.4.

After my apache installation, when I go to my***domain.com, the browser loads my***domain.com/index.html/ instead of my***domain.com/index.html, and I see the error:

```
The requested URL /index.html/ was not found on this server.
```

My sites-available/000-default.conf:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess file in the root of your domain? That could be setting a the default document incorrectly.

Comment: I had that earlier, which I removed. Still the error is same

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a .htaccess file with this text at the top:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

You should also look into .htaccess files, as instead of just getting rid of it, you can do a LOT to speed up your website using it. As well as managing paths to look nice, and many other things.

Comment: I added .htaccess within /var/www/html. Still the error remains the same

Comment: What happens if you navigate to index.html specifically? Same thing?

Comment: Yes. it redirects to index.html/